# Grab values entered in a textarea, to update a column from MySQL (PDO)

Tags: php, pdo

I already searched on all questions how i could do it, but i still can't get my value.

What i am trying to do is : Administrator put some text in a textarea (which is in a POST form), admin hit the button "Send", and then replacing value in database.

I'm using PDO to connect.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 70px;">
      <form method="post" action="../index.php">
        <textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100px;" name="whatupdate"></textarea><br><br>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger" name="subsub">
<?php
  require '../database.php';
          $db = Database::connect();
          $what = $_POST['whatupdate'];
          $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE updator SET marquee = '$what' 
          WHERE updator.id=0;");
          $statement->execute();
?>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, i can't dump value entered in my textarea, so the new value in database is nothing :

http://prntscr.com/i781un

But if i write this :

```
$statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE updator SET marquee = 'ANYKINDOFTEXT' 
              WHERE updator.id=0;");
```

it correctly replaces the column value...

Thank you for reading and bringing answers !

Comment: You're updating the database every time someone visits that page, not only when they actually submit the form. If you enter that site, the `$_POST['whatupdate']` doesn't exist.

Comment: You're also wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Ok, so what should i do? i tried isset (just under), and that didn't work too :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you're resubmitting the code to the same page. Put your php code at the top and wrap it in an `if()` so that it can check for `$_POST['subsub']` and if that exists, then execute the rest of the code.

Also, in your form, change the action to `action=''` just for clarity.

Comment: THANK YOU, it works now, a big thank you, i tried many things, such as using mysqli, mysql for PHP5, and the problem just came from that, i will remember that error ^^

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the variable to post is set. Try whit this code:

```
<?php
      require '../database.php';
      if(isset($_POST['subsub'])):
              $db = Database::connect();
              $what = $_POST['whatupdate'];
              $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE updator SET marquee = :what 
              WHERE updator.id=0;");
              $statement->execute([':what' => $what]);
    endif;
    ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 70px;">
      <form method="post" action="">
        <textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100px;" name="whatupdate"></textarea><br><br>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger" name="subsub">

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but that is the same as the previous one, i mean, the new value in column is nothing, empty :/

Comment: Alright, solved, "action='../index.php'" wasn't good, i should replace by "action=''"

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for the typo fix, i was typing too faster.

Comment: I added prepared statements as well, since the original code was very insecure.